# Get creation and last modification date with branch

Tags: python-2.7, version-control, branch, pysvn

I am trying to use pysvn to get creation and last modification revisions (and above all dates) of files in a svn system...

The typical file history I'm struggling with looks like that :

[image]

I'm using pysvn but I can't understand the documentation very well. So far, either I manage to get branching date/revision or last modification on root... What I would like, is to get real creation date (regardless of if it's in root or branch), and last modification date, excluding branching if there has been no modification in branch since branch creation.

Thanks in advance if someone can provide me help on that, I don't want to spend to much time on this specific part of my script... :)

Manu

(BTW, i'm using an existing simple algo that tries to find creation date using dichotomia, given min and max revisions to check, that checks if file can be found in given revision recursively until the earliest... sorry for that not-very-English explanation!)

(EDIT : of course, for now, branch and root are not merging yet ^^ else I would probably not struggle with the branch revisions and just take merge revision as last modification for instance)

Answer (score 0):

pysvn.Client().log() will return information on commits that you can then analyse.

Of interest to you is the optional changed_paths information, make sure you set discover_changed_paths=True to have this information returned.

That will show you when a file was added to the repo, this is your creation date event. And when a file was modified which is your modified date.

You may also have to figure out that a file was renamed, which looks like a commit with a delete of the original file and the adding of another.

You can also figure out the branch relationship by looking at the value of the copyfrom_path and copyfrom_revision.

Comment: Thanks for the information :)  I kinda left this task for now, but I will dig into the values you mention !